# Arranging Asp.net mvc and web.api in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What would be the best way to structure the project so that we have asp.net mvc and web api in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new template of webApi you get HOME & value Controllers . In HOME CONTROLLER you do the work of  your normal MVC application and In VALUE CONTROLLER which is a API controller do you WEB Api Stuff .

PS: I am working on the same :)

Regards